# Are there drinking water fountains at Birmingham Airport (UK)?

Tags: airports, airport-terminals, tap-water, bhx

Are there drinking water fountains airside at Birmingham International Airport (UK)?

Comment: You have set a new dimension to my understanding of the word `specific`. Amen!

Comment: "After security" could mean airside. Or it could mean landside. it depends on which direction you're going.

Comment: Birmingham International UK and I mean airside - thanks

Comment: Birmingham International Airport airside in the UK is the worst airport I know for a lack of drinking water fountains. There are none in the main departure lounge. It is appalling. There are none marked on the maps and there is no-one to ask.

Comment: @GayotFow I don't think that's a reasonable objection. People talk about "going through security" before departing and "going through customs/immigration/passport control" after landing. I've never heard the word "security" used to describe the things you have to do after landing

Comment: Um, isn't the normal tap water in UK generally perfectly potable?

Answer (score 12):

BHX airside: https://twitter.com/bhx_official/status/253465810289446912

> there are water fountains in our International Pier to fill up. Hope that helps! #bhx

BHM airside: https://youtu.be/-LOzNRZE5A0?t=3m43s the fountain is well visible on the right hand side. (If you rewind to 3m28s you will see it's the bathroom area). As you can see this is gate A5.

IMO "after security" is airside because you do not pass security when landing. If I am wrong, well, others can research landside but I suspect it'll be much harder to find and might require asking on Twitter.

Answer (score 4):

There is one by gate 47, next to the sign. It could not be less obvious and is not signposted or marked on any map. Customer service staff seem unaware of its existence. There is none in any of the main toilets and I couldn't find one in the Flybe/Ryanair hub.

[image: The fountain, on the bottom right, next to the "Gate 47" sign.]

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? or link to any reference?